# firefox launch failed: X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication

Tags: linux, firefox, x11

I logged into a Linux server (RHEL) from an linux desktop. There is not any error message at login, but I failed to launch firefox and see the following error emessage:

```
[myname@myserver ~]$ firefox &
[1] 8806
[myname@myserver ~]$ X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
The application 'firefox' lost its connection to the display localhost:11.0;
most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
the application.
```

I tried to run the following command

```
[myname@myserver ~]$ xhost +
```

but get the following error message:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to localhost:11.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

I also tried to run

```
[myname@myserver ~]$ echo $DISPLAY
```

and got the following result

```
localhost:11.0
```

I tried to search this problem from SO but I had no luck. What is the problem and how can I make the firefox work? It seems that the X window cannot be opened.

Comment: Has the machines ssh-keys been regenerated after you first connected there?

Then you should get a warning message when you connect with ssh from ssh (something along man in the middle warning - host key has changed).

Answer (score 5):

Not all instances of this error message have the same underlying problem. In my case the solution was to

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

Which I found in this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661420/361855f

Comment: This actually works for me on Ubuntu 22.04... Unexpected but it indeed does ... (my issue was xeyes and xterm working but not Firefox)

Comment: This helps to open Firefox window on remote, still, it is not possible to interact with firefox. I upvoted the answer, although it did not solve the issue with Firefox. HOWEVER, I WAS able to use chromium-browser. Ubuntu 2204 on both machines. Thanks

Comment: I am also having issues with Firefox and Ubuntu 22.04.3. This did get rid of the error, but instead of X11 display, it just opened several new firefox window instances on the Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use `xhost +`.  That opens up all sorts of doors and traps.

The best way is to let `ssh` deal with all of this, so do something like this on your local machine

```
$ ssh -X remote.machine.net
```

and once over there, test with a quick

```
$ xlock &
$ xterm &
```

which should pop up on your local box.  Large apps like firefox take a lot longer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this actually does not work. I logged in using ssh -X -l myname remote.machine.net, but neither xclock nor xterm worked. The error messages are: X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to localhost:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Comment: In that case you need to check your ssh configuration. X11 forwarding my be turned off.

Comment: I have the same error as the OP when running Firefox, but when I run xclock and xterm it works! In fact, after I launch xterm I can then try to launch Firefox from within that newly created xterm and it fails with "X11 connection rejected...". The xterm successfully connected over X11 and is tunneling through the ssh -X created prior to typing `xterm`, but Firefox won't work with that same tunnel.

Comment: The world got more complicated than the inventors of the x11 protocol expected :)  Several application have a notion of what they think "their" desktop is and do play along.  If `xclock` works, the (old, plain) `xterm` will too but Gnome Terminal or Konsole may not.  It's been a while since I tried by think Firefox and Chrome also think they know better than you what you actually want :-(

Comment: Lol... well... the same is true of Unix in general, TCP, and even HTTP. I think the real difference here is that not many people, relatively speaking, tunnel x11 connections compared to the number of people that use Unix, TCP, and HTTP. But I appreciate your comment and I see the truth in it.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. Ten, twenty years ago you could just `ssh -X remote` and launch on `remote` to have the 'frames' (ie x11 app) appear locally. Now there are classes of apps for which this no longer works. That has nothing to do with tcp underneath.

Comment: What I mean is that the world got a lot more complicated than the inventors of TCP, HTTP, and the like expected. But since those protocols are widely and daily used by hundreds of millions of people and billions of devices... all the issues have been worked through. Same usage level is not occurring with X11 tunneling over SSH. So the protocol and technology has not kept up with the world around it. So though I agree with the base point of what you said, things would still work if billions of devices were tunneling X11 connections over SSH daily. People would make it work well.